# Changing a changeable content in a fixed page

Tags: javascript

I should create a index page that some parts like header and footer are fixed but the main content is changeable ,
I think I have to set my content into a iframe and change the iframe src with javascript but I dont have any idea how to do this.
How can I do this ? is there any other solutions?

Comment: just look for jquery.ajax, it'll be easy.

Comment: I am noob in ajax , How can I change **just** a part of a page ?

Comment: show what you tried or what you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi perhaps there are better options to consider than frames (which is "bad" practice) if is suitable for your project you could use jquery based scripts as [Pagify](http://bytemuse.com/Pagify/#usage)

or some other of your choice: [JQUERY ONE PAGE SCRIPTS](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/awesome-jquery-plugins-for-creating-single-page-websites/)
In that way you will represent your content in better modern way.
But it always depends on what the final result must be. So if is not the answer please give some more details.

Comment: I think you need to follow my links copy paste working example and construct your page you don't need AJAX that way and will generate all your content at once but not displaying it.

Comment: WoW Thanks, I hate changing frames too its just ugly , I think my problem solved.

Comment: This scripts load all pages at once?

Comment: Yes it load them at once as different divs or li depends of the chosen script just spent some time in learning the script and you will see it is very easy and additionally you will have later a lot of other options. BTW could you mark my answer as answered if you are happy with it.

Comment: Thank you too could you also give +1 :)

Comment: I want but I cant my reputation is under 15.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#wrapper #header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #C90;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
}
#wrapper #main {
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 990px;
    margin-top: 80px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
}
#wrapper #footer {
    background-color: #C60;
    height: 80px;
    width: 1000px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div id="main">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis ligula lorem, consequat eget, tristique nec, auctor quis, purus. Vivamus ut sem. Fusce aliquam nunc vitae purus. Aenean viverra malesuada libero. Fusce ac quam. Donec neque. Nunc venenatis enim nec quam. Cras faucibus, justo vel accumsan aliquam, tellus dui fringilla quam, in condimentum augue lorem non tellus. Pellentesque id arcu non sem placerat iaculis. Curabitur posuere, pede vitae lacinia accumsan, enim nibh elementum orci, ut volutpat eros sapien nec sapien. Suspendisse neque arcu, ultrices commodo, pellentesque sit amet, ultricies ut, ipsum. Mauris et eros eget erat dapibus mollis. Mauris laoreet posuere odio. Nam ipsum ligula, ullamcorper eu, fringilla at, lacinia ut, augue. Nullam nunc.</p>
          <p>.....</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can load data from server to  with using Ajax